# Error handling in PHP class

Tags: php, class, oop

I still playing with PHP and OOP. But not understand how to pull back errors from the class.

**index file**

```
include 'class.php';
$test = new magic('', '', '33');
$test->getfullname();
foreach ($test->get_errors() as $error) {
    echo $error . '<br>';
}
```

**class:**

```
class magic
{

    private $name;
    private $surname;
    private $age;
    private $errors = array();

    function __construct($name, $surname, $age)
    {
        $this->name = $name;
        $this->surname = $surname;
        $this->age = $age;
    }

    public function get_errors()
    {
        return $this->errors;
    }

    public function getname()
    {
        if (!empty($this->name)) {
            return true;
        } else {

            array_push($this->errors, 'Please check name');
            return false;
        }
    }

    public function getsurname()
    {
        if (!empty($this->surname)) {
            return true;
        } else {

            array_push($this->errors, 'Please check surname');
            return false;
        }
    }

    public function getfullname()
    {
        if (($this->getname()) && ($this->getsurname())) {
            echo $this->name . ' ' . $this->surname;
        }
    }

}
```

My question is why when name or surname is empty then returning please check name or surname but when both are empty then return only first? How to candle these type errors in PHP class and what is best practice to do that?
I don't think i can use try/catch exceptions in this scenario.

Comment: short circuit evaluation. if `getName()` returns false, then PHP knows that your `&&` can NEVER evaluate to true, so it doesn't bother calling `getSurname`, because its return value is irrelevant for determining the `&&`'s value.

Comment: @MarcB but in general this pretty much is correct?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php. note the first 4 code lines in the examples.

Comment: @MarcB so i need to add error names into getfullname() function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest handling errors in the constructor and throwing exception.

```
class magic
{

    /**
     * @param string $name
     * @param string $surname
     * @param int $age
     * @throws Exception
     */
    public function __construct($name, $surname, $age)
    {
        $errors = [];

        if (empty($name)) {
            $errors[] = 'Name is required.';
        }

        if (empty($surname)) {
            $errors[] = 'Surname is required.';
        }

        if (!empty($errors)) {
            throw new Exception(implode('<br />', $errors));
        }

        $this->name = $name;
        $this->surname = $surname;
        $this->age = $age;
    }

    public function printFullname()
    {
        echo $this->name . ' ' . $this->surname;
    }

}
```

client:

```
include 'class.php';

try {
    $test = new magic('', '', '33');
    $test->printFullname();
} catch (Exception $exc) {
    echo $exc->getMessage(); //error messages
}
```

Answer (score -1):

There's no reason you can't use exceptions in this scenario, it's what they are designed for, much more elegant than this kind of `$this->geterrors();` stuff.

http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php